# Azure DevOps Pipeline Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, devops

I am getting an error as "Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point
" in my Azure DevOps pipeline.

[image]

And below is my build step.

```
stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage

  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    condition: ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Build
      inputs:
        command: 'build'
        arguments: --output $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      inputs:
        command: publish
        publishWebProjects: true
        arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactsStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
        zipAfterPublish: true
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: $(Build.ArtifactsStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        ArtifactName: drop
```

Please be noted that this is not my complete pipeline, as the error is with the step build, I am pasting only that.

Comment: I ran into a similar problem: I was running `dotnet test` after I ran `dotnet restore` in an Azure pipeline. `dotnet test` threw this error. It turned out the problem was consistency in capitalization of the directory for the project I wanted to test. I had to make sure the directory was capitalized consistently in git, the .sln file and in any .csproj `ProjectReference`. Turns out the actual dotnet process really couldn't find `Program.cs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After scratching my head for a while, basically going through each line in the pipeline, I was able to fix this problem. It was an issue with the build directory. Instead of `arguments: --output $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) --configuration $(buildConfiguration)`, I had to use `arguments: --output $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output --configuration $(buildConfiguration)` so that the final output will be saved inside the `publish_output` folder.

```
stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage

  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    condition: ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Build
      inputs:
        command: 'build'
        arguments: --output $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      inputs:
        command: publish
        publishWebProjects: true
        arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactsStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
        zipAfterPublish: true
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: $(Build.ArtifactsStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        ArtifactName: drop
```

After this change, my pipeline was successful.

[image]

Comment: I had a similar issue were my `-o` was referring to an empty path. Was using a variable that was not declared properly, caused the same error message. Very had to track down, thanks for the hint.